# Error in password recovery

Tags: c#, asp.net, password-recovery

When I was setting up a recover forgot password using passwordrecovery control, I am getting this error.

***The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. hx9sm7431239pbc.68***

And this is my code behind for the recover password:

```
 <add name="Connection" connectionString="Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=CarRental" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
 <system.net>
 <mailSettings>
 <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="notme@gmail.com">
 <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25"/>
 </smtp>
 </mailSettings>
 </system.net>
```

Hope someone can tell me what is wrong with my code. Thank you

Comment: Hope this will help you
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/using-the-passwordrecovery-control-in-Asp-Net-3-5/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net 4.0, you need to set `enableSsl` to true.

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
     <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="notme@gmail.com">
       <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25" enableSsl="true"="true"/>
     </smtp>
   </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Prior to 4.0, you will have to do this in code.
Add it on the [OnSendingMail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.passwordrecovery.onsendingmail%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) event.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
client.Port = 587;
```

Comment: Thanks your answer. But may I know, where to put the client code? Regards

Comment: Add it on the `OnSendingMail` event.